# Display a loading indicator after user taps "Share" and before request is completed?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

The issue I have is that after users tap on the "Share" button of the FBDialog, they do not get any visual feedback until the request completes or fail... and over 3G that can takes a while. During this time users do not know if they tapped "Share" correctly or not, and there's risk of posting content twice.

Is there a way I can get a callback so I can display a loading indicator during this time? Where should I put this piece in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Below code you write to fbAgent.m and also obser code here u get one "PID" at that time u write to alert msg ....... user can understand to that msg was success posted Facebook.

I hope this helps.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([request.method isEqualToString:@"facebook.fql.query"]) {
        NSArray* users = result;
        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];

        // Calling the delegate callback
        [delegate facebookAgent:self didLoadName:name];

    } else if ([request.method isEqualToString:@"facebook.users.setStatus"]) {
        newStatus = nil;
        NSString* success = result;
        if ([success isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

            // Calling the delegate callback
            [delegate facebookAgent:self statusChanged:YES];

        } else {
            [delegate facebookAgent:self statusChanged:NO];
        }
    } else if ([request.method isEqualToString:@"facebook.photos.upload"]) {
        NSDictionary* photoInfo = result;
        NSString* pid = [photoInfo objectForKey:@"pid"];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"success Uploaded Your image please check your FaceBook", pid] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
        fbbut.enabled=YES;
        [fbact stopAnimating];

        self.uploadImageData = nil;
        self.uploadImageCaption = nil;
        self.uploadImageAlbum = nil;
        //[delegate facebookAgent:self photoUploaded:pid];

        if(newStatus){
            [self setStatus:newStatus];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Start your indicator when you click on button and stop on Delegate of Facebook function

```
- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: How do you detect the tap of the button, that's my question. Thank you!